# How to refresh listbox in the windows Phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a `listbox tuningList` containing elements of the `List<Tuning> tunings`:

```
  private void LoadList() {
            foreach (Tuning tuning in tunings)
                tuningList.Items.Add(tuning);
        }
```

At certain point in the app I want to delete some elements in the `tunings` and update the `listbox`

```
 int selectionIndex = tuningList.SelectedIndex;
            if (selectionIndex >= 0) {
                pageTitle.Text = "Deleted tuning";
                tunings.RemoveAt(selectionIndex);
               // tuningList.Items.RemoveAt(selectionIndex);
                saveData(saver); //saves data to isolated storage 

            }
```

but after that listbox does not update itself.

EDIT: I did not bind the listbox to the collection via XAML, I added the elements by the LoadList();

```
<ListBox x:Name="tuningList" Margin="8,0,8,152" Tap="tuningList_Tap"/>
```

EDIT2:

```
<ListBox x:Name="tuningList" Margin="8,0,8,152" ItemsSource=tunings.Items Tap="tuningList_Tap"/>
```

EDIT3:

```
<ListBox  x:Name="tuningList" Margin="8,0,8,152"  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ItemsSource="{Binding tunings}" Tap="tuningList_Tap"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My piece of advice in this case would be binding your `ListBox` control to an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28VS.95%29.aspx), which will automatically notify the view when an item is added or removed due to the fact that it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

You need to bind the collection to the `ListBox`. Instead of using `LoadList` set the `ItemsSource` in XAML. Otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: Too much change in the whole application(not enough time) is there any so clean solution?

Comment: You don't really have too much to change, since you can use pretty much the same calls on ObservableCollection<T> as you would on List<T>.

Comment: I did it but unfortunatelly the listbox is not updated. Maybe I bind it wrong.

Comment: Can you update your post to show how you're binding the collection to the `ListBox` control?

Comment: http://wklej.org/hash/478fa086f3d/ I bind it exacly the same way as in the original post.

Comment: I did it in XAML but the problem is that in xaml compilator does not see ObservableCollection tunings.

Comment: You are not using the proper binding string. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052368/303696

Comment: EDIT3 in main post. Did it but now if I don't call the LoadList() nothing appears so I do not think it is bound correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22603/discussion-between-den-delimarsky-and-robert-kilar)